# FromQuery ModelBinding fails, FromBody works

Tags: c#, datatables, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use a standard set of classes for binding server side DataTables.net grids to data sources.

```
public class DataTable
    {
        // Grid properties
        public int draw { get; set; }
        public List<DataTableColumn> columns { get; set; }
        public List<DataTableOrder> order { get; set; }
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public DataTableColumnSearch search { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataTableColumn
    {
        public string data { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool searchable { get; set; }
        public bool orderable { get; set; }
        public DataTableColumnSearch search { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataTableColumnSearch
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public bool regex { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataTableOrder
    {
        public int column { get; set; }
        public string dir { get; set; }
    }

    public class Grid
    {
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
        public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
        public object data { get; set; }

        public void Setup<T>(IQueryable<T> r, DataTable p)
        {
            // Filter, sort and bind the data data to this.data
        }
    }
```

Then, in MVC 5 I was able to use the `QueryString` model binding:
`public async Task<JsonResult> GetDataTable(DataTable p)`

Everything was bound, and the column, search and order objects were all set.

I'm setting up a new project in .NET Core and this now only works if you accept `[HttpPost]` and post the DataTables.net request to the controller.

If I use the `[HttpGet]` method, then the `DataTable` object binds correctly, but no child items (`DataTableColumn`, `DataTableSearch` or `DataTableOrder`) bind.

The Form Data and QueryString data are the same:

```
draw:1
columns[0][data]:Col1
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:Col2
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:asc
start:0
length:10
search[value]:v6
search[regex]:false
```

I'd prefer to use a `GET` request, as it is getting data, so shouldn't need to post. As said, this was working in MVC 5, so I'm not sure what has changed?

---

**EDIT TO ADD**

As per the comments, it's just using the standard model binder:

```
 public class OutboundCaims: Controller
 {
     //[HttpGet]
     [HttpPost]
     [Route("Claims")]
     public async Task<JsonResult> GetClaims(DataTable p) {  }
 }
```

If using POST, the DataTable class is bound correctly by the model binder, using GET it isn't. Both POST and GET produce the same output as above when viewed in Chrome dev tools, so pretty sure it's not that.

The request is made using the standard set of jQuery ajax requests built into DataTables.net.

---

Edit to add: **REQUEST URL** using a `GET` method:

`http://localhost:55319/api/DataTable?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=col1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=col2&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=contract&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=manufacturer&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=owner&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1478804216098`

This maps to the same as the POST request, just the model binder doesn't work.

Comment: Could you update your answer adding your API Controller and how you're making your GET/POST request?

Comment: There's the [FromBody] model binding (GetClaims([FromBody] DataTable p)). I'm not sure if this will work. But I recommend you to use POST Method since you're sending data inside the body. You should use GET if you send the data in your URL (as a query parameter or in your route).

Comment: As said, it can be sent in the query string or the body, depending if you tell datatables to use a GET or POST. I'd like to use GET as the request is getting data, not inserting data. If it's either POST or GET, the data is the same just the GET doesn't get bound. I'll share an example querystring later on.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it was always going inside the body. Did you try to use `[FromQuery]` with the GET Method?

Comment: Yep, and as said like that it binds the main data table object but not the child objects. It did work seamlessly in mvc 5, so just something different with core

Comment: Ok, so the problem is how Ajax is creating your GET URL. I have a GET Method that expect a IList<int> as parameter. The URL is something like this: myurl?p1=1&p1=2&p1=3... Can you check how is your URL?

Comment: @FabricioKoch I've added the GET version. This maps the same... In you IList<int> example, is that in .NET Core? And the first level work, it's the child items which do not map.